# Make required validation conditional in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I do a required validation a given field based on the value of another completely different field?

Comment: Be more specific.  Required what?  What kind of field?

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW I need to validate if the user input data in one field, based on the value of another field.  My first field is a text input (id supplier), the second is a collection_select (supplier type), if the user input a id supplier that doesn't exists, I need to make "required" the supplier type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
attr_accessible :supplier_id, :supplier_type

validates :supplier_type, :presence  => true,
    :if => lambda{ check_supplier_exists }

def check_supplier_exists
  @supplier = Supplier.find(self.supplier_id)
  if @supplier != nil
    return true
  else 
    return false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the unless [conditions on validations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html).

Here you have an [example](http://lindsaar.net/2010/1/31/validates_rails_3_awesome_is_true):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :post_code, :presence => true, :unless => :no_postcodes?

  def no_postcodes?
    ['TW'].include?(country_iso)
  end

end
```